# Selenium - Headless ChromeOptions Ignoring While loop?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

Running into this odd problem. Not quite sure how to resolve it!

When I add

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
```

to my code, it ignores the subsequent While loop.

Here is my full code, up to the end of the script: (with redacted url)

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')



    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("SomeURL")
    button = driver.find_element_by_id('show_more')
    count = 1
    while count > 0:
        button.click()
        count = count + 1
        time.sleep(2)
        if count == 50000:
            break

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')



 img_data = []
 for img_tag in soup.find_all('img'):
     data_dict = dict()
     data_dict['image_name'] = img_tag['alt']
     data_dict['image_url'] = img_tag['src']
     img_data.append(data_dict)

with open('osprey.csv', 'w', newline='') as birddata:
     fieldnames = ['image_name', 'image_url']
     writer = csv.DictWriter(birddata, fieldnames=fieldnames)
     writer.writeheader()
     for data in img_data:
         writer.writerow(data)
```

The code above runs headless, but only returns 30 results and writes to CSV. (while loop is not being processed). When:

`options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
 options.add_argument('headless')`

is removed, and `driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)` is modified to `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` the process works, and returns over 10,000 results and writes to CSV, but is not headless and takes a long time to load the page's images.

I am scraping millions of images, so I really need this to be headless for efficiency. Any tips on keeping it headless while still keeping my loop running would be fantastic.

TIA! - Cheers!

Comment: Some code is missing from that loop - in the current form it will never reach the scraping part as it's an infinite loop. The counter is not decremented. Please revise a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @skandigraun

Comment: @skandigraun fixed the loop. Any tips on the headless issue? still not resolved

Answer (score 0):

You should set it like below

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

[refer](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/chrome/options.py):

```
def to_capabilities(self):
    """
        Creates a capabilities with all the options that have been set and
        returns a dictionary with everything
    """
    caps = self._caps
    chrome_options = self.experimental_options.copy()
    chrome_options["extensions"] = self.extensions
    if self.binary_location:
        chrome_options["binary"] = self.binary_location
    chrome_options["args"] = self.arguments
    if self.debugger_address:
        chrome_options["debuggerAddress"] = self.debugger_address

    caps[self.KEY] = chrome_options
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that version received DepracationWarning. I have tried that version syntax as well.